# aiohttp php like arrays in post

Tags: python, post, http-post, aiohttp

I have recieved array:

```
MultiDict({'data[0]': 'test', 'data[1]': 'test', 'data[2]': 'test', 'hash': 'b5a1f45733f0949ed80f1ef4eaef5454667e4eeb0b77233e15a796e6c91c088b'})
```

I need to iterate datas like php`s sorted array:

```
foreach ($_POST["data"] as $entry) {
    $hash .= $entry;
}
```

In php `hash == 'testtesttest'`

Trying

```
>>> keys = list(filter( lambda x: x.split('[')[0] == 'data', post.keys()))
>>> list(keys)
['data[0]', 'data[1]', 'data[2]']
>>> for x in keys:
...    print(int( x.split('[')[1].split(']')[0] ))
... 
0
1
2
>>> sorted(keys, key = lambda x : int( x.split('[')[1].split(']')[0] ))
['data[0]', 'data[1]', 'data[2]']
>>> for k in keys:
...     hash += post[k]
```

Comment: post the desired output/result

Answer (score 2):

With sorted keys and `str.startswith` function:

```
# sample dict
d = {'data[2]': 'test2', 'data[1]': 'test1', 'data[10]': 'test10',
     'data[0]': 'test0', 'hash': 'b5a1f45733f0949ed80f1ef4eaef5454667e4eeb0b77233e15a796e6c91c088b'}

data = ''.join(d[k] for k in sorted((k_ for k_ in d.keys() if k_.startswith('data[')),
                                    key=lambda x: int(x.strip('data[]'))))
print(data)
```

The output:

```
test0test1test2test10
```

Comment: is this fully compatable with phps realisation?

Comment: @eri, Python does **not** have to be compatible with Php  or mimic it. They are different.